# iOS: UIVIew back to start position after segue and popViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have UIViewController, there is some animation in these UIViewController. UIView that animates on this UIViewController has different start and end position. I also have segue, that will push new UIViewController to the scene. All works okay, but if I return to my first UIViewController, position of my UIVIew changes to start position.

How can I fix this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3  animations:^{


            self.myView.center = CGPointMake(self.myView.center.x,self.ahotherView.center.y);


        }completion:^(BOOL complete){
        }];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.myView.center = CGPointMake(self.myView.center.x, self.ahotherView.center.y);

}
```

Comment: Do you have some position settings for the view in question in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear or viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews in the controller that you are returning to? Cause all of those methods will be called.

Comment: @AntonijoDev no, I haven't. I tried to fix this in those method, but I can't.

Comment: @AntonijoDev I actually can fix this, but I can see how my `UIView` jumps to end position. (Want it without this jump). To fix this, I change code in `
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: are you using popViewController method to go back? and segue to go forward?

Comment: @AntonijoDev I'm using `pushViewController` and `popViewController`, I tried this with segue and back button of navigation controller (same result)

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: @AntonijoDev ok, but it's pretty default, I'll edit my question

Comment: what happened if you remove self.myView.center = CGPointMake(s... code from - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: @AntonijoDev my `UIView` (self.myView) will stay on its start position that is higher that I need it, but it's position necessary for animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autolayout is causing it to return to the beginning position. You can either turn it off or write a bit of code to override the constraints.

You'll have to first add constraints in Storyboard, which is an entirely different question in itself. I recommend doing some research. Once you've added the proper constraints and created `IBOutlet`s for them, you'll be changing the values of the constraint constants, then calling `[self.myView layoutIfNeeded]` inside your animation block. Instead of changing the `center` property. Might look something like this:

```
//update constraint values
self.topConstraint.constant = 70;
self.bottomConstraint.constant = 20;

//animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.myView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Comment: trying to implement this.

Comment: nice edit about Constraints `IBOutlet`s! Didn't know that I can make it. I solve my problem:) Thanks you:)

Comment: On popping back to my original VC, all of my UI elements were moving down. The only things that solved this was turning off autolayout in IB. Thanks for the suggestion.